# SQL correlated subquery returning no results

Tags: sql, subquery, correlated

I'm trying to better understand how correlated subqueries work. Using https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

the query below is my attempt to use a correlated subquery to list the products with price greater than the average price of all products. It returns no records.

```
SELECT p1.ProductID, p1.Price
FROM PRODUCTS p1
WHERE p1.Price > 
    (SELECT AVG(p2.Price)
    FROM PRODUCTS p2
        WHERE p2.ProductID = p1.ProductID);
```

Number of Records: 0

| ProductID | Price |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |

When I modify the query to run as a non-correlated subquery (below), it runs fine and returns results.

```
SELECT p1.ProductID, p1.Price
FROM PRODUCTS p1
WHERE p1.Price > 
    (SELECT AVG(p2.Price)
    FROM PRODUCTS p2);
```

Number of Records: 25

| ProductID | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 30 |
| 8 | 40 |
| 9 | 97 |
| 10 | 31 |
| etc. |  |

What am I missing? Why is the correlated subquery failing to return any records? I would expect that when "WHERE p2.ProductID = p1.ProductID" evaluates to true, the nested query would return AVG(p2.Price) and compare it to p1.Price. When p1.Price is greater than AVG(p2.Price), the record should be added to the result set. Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: please post the original data and the desired output

Comment: The correlated sub-query is invoked separately for each product id *(because that's what you correlated the query on, in the sub-query's where clause)*. So, when the outer query evaluates a row with product_id=1, your correlated sub-query returns the average price of all rows with product_id=1. As no product has a price higher than its own average price, the outer query returns nothing. Run this to see what it's doing: `SELECT p1.ProductID, p1.price, (SELECT AVG(p2.Price) FROM PRODUCTS p2 WHERE p2.ProductID = p1.ProductID) FROM PRODUCTS p1`

Comment: That's helpful... I see more clearly why there is no output: because every time p1.Price is compared to the subquery result, the two vaules are equal. Therefore it's never true that p1.Price > AVG(p2.Price). @DannySlor The original data is 77 records long, so I'll just point to it:  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all  SELECT ProductID, Price FROM PRODUCTS. The desired output (25 rows, truncated) is in the post...

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: A correlated subquery is not needed for this result, roughly speaking because a join is not needed. You don't need to extract a value based on a function of (parts of) a row; a correlated subquery expresses such a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this would work, as it select the avg that have a bigger ProductId

```
SELECT * FROM Products p2
WHERE Price > (SELECT AVG(Price) FROM Products WHERE ProductID > p2.ProductID);
```

result:
[image]

your problem, is that the correlated subquery will only get you the Avaerage of the one product that is in the row, so the price and AVG(Price= is identical, as only one value is present to be calculated, so it never can be bigger.

If you change the WHERE to something that gets more than one row, you can get results

Comment: The modification you suggested is helpful. Strangely, it returns 30 rows rather than the 25 I expected when I ran it as a standard subquery, as shown in the original post. I'm trying to figure out which rows were omitted and why.

Comment: this was only a sample query to demonstrate how correlated subqueries work. To interpret the query you must know that sql databases, work row by row, and the query takes the first row, gets all rows that have a higher id and build the average and compare that finally. the rest is math as the averaage of the last rows can be higher than some or most of the rows